flutter run not running on mac
I am trying to run flutter run command but it is giving me this error why ??
I am trying to do everything i even change grade file also but then also it is not working.
flutter run --android-skip-build-dependency-validation
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/nidhigodhani/Downloads/flutter_realtime_object_detection/android/settings.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '{agpVersion}', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:{agpVersi
on}')                                                                                                                              Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,862ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1



I want answer of this

From this line:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '{agpVersion}', apply: false]

It looks like the agpVersion variable is not defined and therefore the Gradle cannot find it.
Define your version directly, like this:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false]

Note: You should specify a compatible AGP version here according to your Gradle version.

in which file do i have to make edit in order to archive this ??

In your project, look for android/settings.gradle file.
